# With what I should replace dirX for my bullets to shoot right and left

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing a 2d game and I want to know how I can make the bullets to shoot right and left . At this moment the bullets go just to the left , even if my player moves right. How I can make them shoot both sides or shoot just when they find an object tagged " enemy "

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    float dirX;

    [SerializeField]
    float moveSpeed = 5f, jumpForce = 400f, bulletSpeed = 500f;


    Vector3 localScale;

    public Transform barrel;
    public Rigidbody2D bullet;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        localScale = transform.localScale;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        dirX = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            Jump();

        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            Fire();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }





    void Jump()
    {
        if (rb.velocity.y == 0)
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);
    }

    void Fire()
    {
        var firedBullet = Instantiate(bullet, barrel.position, barrel.rotation);
        firedBullet.AddForce(barrel.up * bulletSpeed);
    }

}
```

Comment: The parameter passed in `firedBullet.AddForce` is what determines the direction. It's not clear what barrel is, but try factoring in your `dirX` float, for instance.

Comment: the barrel it's at the end of the gun where it is supposed to shoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already accounting for the direction of the barrel. You just need to change the direction of the barrel when you move.

One way to do that is to just set that directly:

```
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        dirX = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (dirX !=0)
        {
            barrel.up = Vector3.right * Mathf.Sign(dirX);
        }

        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            Jump();

        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            Fire();
    }
```

If the barrel is a child of the player object, then changing the character's rotation so that the barrel's direction points in the correct direction will also work. There's not enough information in the question to know for sure but maybe using [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to set the character's rotation like so would work:

```
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        dirX = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (dirX !=0)
        {
            Vector3 newPlayerForward = Vector3.forward * Mathf.Sign(dirX);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newPlayerForward, Vector3.up);
        }

        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            Jump();

        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            Fire();
    }
```